# Audio Playback Headaches

Tags: android, media-player, recording, playback, audiorecord

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I have been able to get the audio recording to work good, as well as level meters. I have moved onto playback of audio, which is causing me some headaches.  I have read various articles relating to MediaPlayer and AudioTrack and some of the differences between the two classes.  One thing that I did read was that both classes support PCM, which is the format of my recorded audio.

In the recording of audio, I am using the AudioRecord class to capture 16-bit PCM mono data.  I am capturing the data and then writing the data to a file that is saved to the SD card.  Here is the core of the code to write to the file:

```
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (dis.available() > 0 )
        {
            dos.writeShort(dis.readShort());
        }
```

and here is the code for writing the WAVE header:

```
    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
```

The problem is with the playback of the audio file.  MediaPlayer is really quick when it comes to playback but the result is loud static.  I am taking the file that was created with the code above and trying to push it through MediaPlayer for playback.  From what I have read, MediaPlayer supports 16-bit PCM audio, which I believe I have created above.

```
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    File file = new File(mFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
    mPlayer.prepare();
    mPlayer.start();
```

When I use AudioTrack, the audio playback is normal, meaning the audio is as it was recorded.  The big problem with using this class is the latency that I am experiencing when trying to start the playback.  I am using Stream mode and it is taking 5-15 seconds for the audio to start the playback, which is totally unacceptable.

Here is the code that I have for calling the AudioTrack class:

```
    int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 
           AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
           AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    audioPlayer = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 
                      AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                       intSize, 
                       AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    short[] byteData = null;
    File file = null;
    file = new File(mFileName);

    InputStream is  = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;

    try 
    {
        is = new FileInputStream( file );
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
        int size = (int) file.length();
        audioPlayer.play();

        byteData = new short[size/2];

    while (dis.available() > 0 )
    {
        byteData[ret] = dis.readShort();
        ret++;
    }
    if (byteData != null ) 
    { 
        //  Write the byte array to the track 
        audioPlayer.write(byteData,0, ret); 
        bytesread += ret; 
    } 

    dis.close();

    is.close(); 
    audioPlayer.stop(); 
    audioPlayer.release();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the static when using MediaPlayer?  Or any ideas on how to improve the performance when using AudioTrack?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)?

Comment: When I was first developing on the application, I was encountering a crash in MediaRecorder when initializing the class with the microphone.  The more I read, it seemed as though AudioRecord was the better class to use.  Upon the implementation, I was no longer encountering any crashes.

Comment: If you plan on playing back audio rapidly and the file isn't too large consider using SoundPool.

Comment: I looked at the SoundPool class but one article that I found said that it is not recommended for audio files > 1 mb in size.  Since I am working with PCM files, I am bound to run over this limit.